# Django and pure Python

Tags: python, django, selenium

I want to create a web app with Django and integration of Selenium and Python-Docker API.
Where inside the Django project is the correct place to put the Selenium scripts so users will be able the run it by a puse of a button?
I've seen some thred saying inside a 'view', but is is a lot of logic that I've sprated into multipale .py files.

Comment: If you mean a button in a browser, then yes, a view. Programming is work. Many hours went in to Django to make it do what it does easily.

Comment: OK, and if I want it to run automatically? I have a Docker function that creates new containers. It runs perfectly, but what will be that best way to make it run every time a new user is register? I want it to keep the container's id as foreign key for the user. some sort of Post_Save signal?

Answer (score 1):

You must import `Selenium` package inside another file such as `sel-functions.py` inside your app.

Then you define your class or functions inside this file. Finally you can import all those functionality to your `views.py` file.

This is best and cleanest way to work with another package or functionality in Django project. 
Also if multiple apps of your project need to `sel-functions.py`  you can put that in your project directory beside `settings.py`.

> Also, if your code has grown so much that it has multiple files, you
>   need to define a package for your intended work and define it as an
>   application in your project.